# Custom Snapshots Configuration for static data only

Tags: acumatica

Does anyone ever modified the Snapshots Configuration to create snapshots excluding all transactions?

I was looking at this blog post : https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2015/11/configuring-own-snapshots.html

I need to be able to generate snapshots that includes business accounts, settings, Inventory , users and contacts except attachments.

The sales orders, invoices , shipments , issues , receipts , transfers , all transactions would be ignored ...

Thanks,

Mauricio

I can exclude some tables but there's many relationships that I might be missing.

Comment: How is this different from the "Settings and Business Accounts Except Attachments" configuration?

Comment: I would agree with Samvel... there is already a snapshot configuration which does what you are asking